# Different property values are returned for user defined exception in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I have 2 stored procedures which have identical structure of if-else condition and raises an error if the condition fails:

```
IF @CurrentConcurrencyCheck = @ConcurrencyCheck
    BEGIN
        -- SQL Statements
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Concurrency Exception',16,1)
    END
```

and in the DAL I am catching the concurrency exception as:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
        _property.DatabaseError = ex.InnerException.ToStringNullSafe();

        if (_property.DatabaseError.Contains("Concurrency"))
            _property.IsConcurrencyError = true;
        else
            _property.IsConcurrencyError = false;

        return false;
}
```

Now in one stored procedure the `InnerException` contains the text which I am returning as "Concurrency Exception" while the `Message` property contains text

> An error has occurred........

While in the other the `InnerException` is null but the `ex.message` property contains the text "Concurrency Exception".

Why I am getting different behaviour for the same code? And is there a better way to return a user defined exception?

Comment: is there any error handling in the stored procedures?

Comment: no there is no error handling. in both the cases when the if condition is not met, I am getting the text "concurrency exception" but in different properties of exception object. In other words the ELSE condition is executed on both occassions.